# Are questions about scientific computing employment on topic?

Tags: discussion, topicality

[This question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2036/scicomp-modeling-jobs) just came up about where to find jobs in scientific computing / modeling. While certainly an important question for many of us, it seems a bit off-topic to me.  Also, it is phrased as a subjective list-like question whose answer would certainly vary over time...

Any thoughts on it?

Comment: Paul, see http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/255/are-the-questions-about-the-career-path-as-a-computational-scientist-appropriate and associated answers.